# How to interpret this traceback?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, windows-8.1, pycharm

I'm setting up a new development machine and installed my IDE pycharm. I installed python to `C:\Program (x86)\python27`. But when I start my gae server I get this traceback. What does it mean?

```
pydev debugger: process 7576 is connecting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 155, in main
    sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 189, in enable_sandbox
    from google.appengine.runtime import runtime
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\runtime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from google.appengine.runtime import cgi
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\cgi.py", line 32, in <module>
    from email import feedparser
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 829, in load_module
    return self.import_stub_module(fullname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 841, in import_stub_module
    __import__(fullname, {}, {})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\socket.py", line 73, in <module>
    from _ssl import RAND_add, RAND_egd, RAND_status, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, SSL_ERROR_SSL, SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, SSL_ERROR_EOF, SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd
pydev debugger: process 2496 is connecting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\_python_runtime.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime.py", line 155, in main
    sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 189, in enable_sandbox
    from google.appengine.runtime import runtime
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\runtime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from google.appengine.runtime import cgi
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\cgi.py", line 32, in <module>
    from email import feedparser
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\charset.py", line 13, in <module>
    import email.base64mime
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\base64mime.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.utils import fix_eols
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 829, in load_module
    return self.import_stub_module(fullname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 841, in import_stub_module
    __import__(fullname, {}, {})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\socket.py", line 73, in <module>
    from _ssl import RAND_add, RAND_egd, RAND_status, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, SSL_ERROR_SSL, SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, SSL_ERROR_EOF, SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd
```

If I run as admin `pip install PyOpenSLL` then I get

```
C:\>pip install pyopensll
Collecting pyopensll
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopensll (from versio
ns: )
No matching distribution found for pyopensll

C:\>pip install pyOpenSSL
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in c:\progra
m files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in c:\progr
am files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cryptography>=0.7 in c
:\program files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\progr
am files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in c:\program f
iles (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in c:\program f
iles (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna in c:\program fil
es (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in c:\progra
m files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=0.8 in c:\progra
m files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in c:\progra
m files (x86)\python27\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography>=0.7->pyO
penSSL)

C:\>
```

Comment: You can not import `RAND_egd`. See `ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd` (last line).

Comment: It is complaining that it cannot find RAND_egd which should be there

Comment: I reinstalled pip still getting the same error. There are no hits in google for `cannot import name RAND_egd`

Answer (score 4):

New:

It seems that you use LibreSSl instead of OpenSSL. See [Python: Issue 21356](http://bugs.python.org/issue21356)

Check if you're using LibreSSL by running this in python-shell:

```
from ssl import OPENSSL_VERSION; print OPENSSL_VERSION
```

Old:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\socket.py", line 73, in <module>
    from _ssl import RAND_add, RAND_egd, RAND_status, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, SSL_ERROR_SSL, SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, SSL_ERROR_EOF, SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd
```

is the essential for you to know. In pretty easy writing, it means:
"Google's app engine is unable to find a Name called RAND_egd in module _ssl"

<strike>Try to update all packages.</strike>

Try `from _ssl Import RAND_egd` from console, then put results here.

Comment: If I do it from the console then I get an `ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd`.

Comment: This is a fresh install. I have one ubuntu machine where the development environment works perfectly. Now I'm trying to set up the dev environment on a MS-Windows 8.1 machine and I've gotten this far. If it matters, I put my python installation in `C:\Program (x86)\python27` instead of `C:\python`

Comment: Do you know what the problem might be? I don't understand why it's not working. My other installation runs just fine, that is Ubuntu.

Comment: For this, see: [Python 2.7 - ssl.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ssl.py) on line 108-112. There it's also described: >> LibreSSL does not provide RAND_egd

Comment: `>>> from ssl import OPENSSL_VERSION; print OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015` But what can I do about it?

Comment: The funny Thing is: I have also Windows 8.1, `print OPENSSL_VERSION` doesn't work (Not found), but RAN_egd is accessible. Please try: `pip install pyOpenSSL`

Comment: When I try to install pyOpenSSL it says that it is already installed. What should I do?

Comment: You may need to run the command with administrator privileges.

Comment: @Nick I get "Requirement already satisfied" from `pip install pyOpenSLL` run as administrator (Win 8.1). I also have an ubuntu machine where this environement is working.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, the public Issue list doesn't have any bugs mentioning RAND_egd. I recommend [filing a bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) against this problem, including the stack trace and mentioning that you're seeing this on Windows 8.1. Include a link to to this stackoverflow question.

That still leaves you with an immediate problem, so consider trying this experiment: Edit `google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\socket.py` and remove the reference to RAND_egd (leaving a copy of the original line commented out, or make a copy of socket.py, so that you can revert the change easily). Then see what happens. You might get lucky. And please report back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to file a bug report. If I comment out the RAND_egd reference then I get this error `ImportError: No module named wtforms` but wtforms is actually there. It works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Stuff like this used to drive me nut when working near the SDK. Things would work fine, then an OS (usually) or Python (seldomly) release would tip over the cart on one platform until we could a fix into the next release. Sorry that you're on the wrong end of it.

Comment: I now filed it as issue 12176. Thank you for the help.  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12176&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log